# How to automatically fade out list view items one by one in Android?

Tags: android, listview

As title.

in getView() I try to flag each item if it's been applied animation yet.
If not, then apply it. Code as below:

```
final View finalV = v;
if (finalV.getTag() == null) {
    finalV.setTag(true);
    finalV.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(1000).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finalV.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(1000).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

but it doesn't work as I expected. How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an RecyclerView with an ItemAnimator. I suppose you are using a ListView since the RecyclerView adapters don't use the getView() method anymore.

If you chose to upgrade to the RecyclerView, you can customize the ItemAnimator however you'd like, and you don't need to worry about 'remembering' which item you have animated and which item you haven't.

Take a look at this article:

[Replacing ListView with RecyclerView](https://traversoft.com/blog/2016/01/31/replace-listview-with-recyclerview/)

Comment: Thank @tim687. I took your advice and it works now :)